# Amazon Redshift: Is it possible to return multiple result set?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I've a complex query with multiple common table expression. Along with the final result set , would I be able to get data from one of the common table expression which i used inbetween.

e.g : fetch overall sale % along with saleID for a given range

```
with saleDataRange as 
 (select *  from saleTable where ...
 )
with resultset1 as 
(
  ...
)
select salePercent from resultset1 where ...
```

The above query will return only salePercent. But I want the intermediate resultset1 common table too. Any hint?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support multiple result sets, so I really doubt Redshift (which is based on a heavily modified very old PostgreSQL 8.1 release) does. The usual solution in PostgreSQL is a function returning `SETOF REFCURSOR` but you can't do that in Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

I returned the multiple unrelated result set using below 2 methods in redshift amazon.

1. Using a CTE, full outer join and row_num
2. using a CTE, union all and null columns

And also I used temporary table to fetch multiple result separately.